# Deploying React Vite app via symlink to dist folder on cPanel

Tags: reactjs, deployment, cpanel, symlink

I'm currently deploying my React Vite app on a VPS using cPanel. I have a script that pulls the application from github, installs the dependencies, builds the app and copies contents of the dist folder into the public_html folder.

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way I can symlink the contents of the public_html folder to the dist folder so I can remove the copy step?

The trick is I also have a .htaccess and an api subdirectory in the public_html folder, so I can't have the public_html folder be a direct symlink to the dist folder as this wouldn't include the these files.

My current directory setup:

```
/home/user/frontend -> contains full react code
/home/user/frontend/dist -> contains built react code
/home/user/public_html -> contains copy of dist folder
/home/user/public_html/api -> a symlink to the php backend
```

The public_html folder currently contains the following:

```
.htaccess
index.html -> copied from dist
favicon.png -> copied from dist
/assets -> copied from dist
/api
```

Is there a standard way of achieving this, or am I approaching it wrong and there is a better way of doing this all together?